# Why does my furnace blower work intermittently?

Tags: blower, relay, motor

On my Goodman 3.5 ton AC/ furnace, the blower seems to only run when it wants. I changed the capacitor on the blower twice and the thermostat once- same. If it doesn't start, I turn it off for 5 minutes and then back on, it works- but only sometimes. It does this in both modes.

Comment: Please provide the model number of the furnace. Also the make/model of the thermostat would help a lot. Also, please don't yell at us - we can read proper cased titles just as easily.

Comment: Yes, can you post the make/model of the unit, and its wiring diagram for that matter?

Comment: When the thermostat is calling for heat but the blower isn't running, does the control board in the furnace have any LEDs or other indicators showing any kind of trouble or fault code?